# Cartesian features into 1D features for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have two 1:1 arrays of data, that can be plotted on a Cartesian x and y graph. These two arrays represent one sample to then predict later.

```
# data structure with two dimensions, x and y

sample[0] = [1, 2, 3]
sample[1] = [5, 5, 5]
```

How can I shape this feature input (x and y) with Python for a machine learning features table: (features.csv)

Not sure about this part:

```
feature1, feature2, feature3
'(1, 5)', '(2, 5)', '(3, 5)'
```

Can I do x * y simply for each?

For more info the target format (targets.csv):

```
class a
class b
```

I have a working example with 1D features. This is the 1D example: https://github.com/amstuta/random-forest

I'm trying to use a Cartesian 2D input of x and y, instead of 1D for each feature.

Comment: What does this have to do with machine learning? Do you need this operation done within a specific library or framework, or do you need it to run on some specific platform? Otherwise, it seems like a fairly straightforward Python question? `list(zip(sample[0], sample[1]))` - plain Python, no imports.

Comment: This has to do with shaping 2D features for 1D feature input for machine learning, and how to do this the easiest way with Python. Does any further data cleaning need to be done to feed this into a generic Random Forest? I have a working example with 1D features. Trying to expand that to 2D features.

Comment: You can use the operation for many things, but if you're asking how to get from two lists, to a single lists with elements from the first two paired, the answer is `list(zip(list1, list2))` - no machine learning involved. You can apply it to machine learning code just fine though. If that's *not* what you're asking, please provide some more code and context and show why you cannot use this basic command in this case.